# richfaces 4 tabpanel with 3 tabs-Beans for all the three includes being invoked when the main page is called

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, include, richfaces, managed-bean

Below is my main page where i am including three tabs.
The problem is when i am loading this home page, the managed beans for each of the page are getting called at once.
My understanding was, if we use the switch type as 'server', the beans would be referred on the respective tab click only.Please correct me if am wrong
All the managed beans I am using are session beans.I changed it to request as well but ths behavior was still persistent.

```
            <ui:include src="/xhtml/Page1.xhtml" />
    </rich:tab>

<rich:tab name="Page2" id="tab2" label="PageTab2">
<!-- Tab content here -->

       <ui:include src="/xhtml/Page2.xhtml" />

</rich:tab>
<rich:tab name="Page3" id="tab3" label="PageTab3">
<!-- Tab content here-->

    <ui:include src="/xhtml/Page3.xhtml" />
</rich:tab>
```

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with your bean scope as the provisions that Richfaces gives with regard to tab loading only kicks in after first load. When a facelets page is loaded for rendering, **every** backing component referenced in it is evaluated AND backing beans are initialized, per standard JSF view loading. The lazy loading of RF tabs kicks in on subsequent requests

Comment: @kolossus..Thank you.The problem is when my tabbed page loads, i could see a lot of calls made to all my backing beans.Due to this, the page loads takes some amount of time.So,wanted to check ,if the rendering of the inactive pages or their bean initialization can be held till the point when the corresponding tab gets clicked.